# xcode UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest about:///#page1

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, nsurlrequest

i try to use UIWebView as PDF Viewer,

> [self.webView loadData:myPdf MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:url];  its work fine

i have issues with the links format in the #shouldStartLoadWithRequest

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { return YES;}
```

there 2 cases :

1. When the name of the destination file contain no space : ex =>/link/to/my/**xfile.pdf** => i got the whole url throught the request param of shouldStartLoadWithRequest function  (fine for me)
2. When the name of the destination file contain space : => /link/to/my/**2 file file.pdf** => i got this string  ***about:///#page1*** as URL in the request param

any Ideas

Thanks

Comment: Is there an easy way for you to percent encode your url? If I am understanding correctly, what has the spaces in it is the base url string. Am I correct? I might be misunderstanding though.

Comment: What URL you get with first case?

Comment: Is there an easy way for you to percent encode your url? i can not  decode it, because i can not get the url aven with %20

Comment: with first case i got the whle good url, **/link/to/my/xfile.pdf**